# Why accuracy of SCE-UA optimization algorithm are different when implemted in Julia and MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, julia

I rewrite the SCE-UA optimization algorithm in Julia.

However, when I run my script in Julia. The optimized value is quite different from the results in MATLAB. The global best cost in MATLAB is 2.4598e-63 while the global best cost in Julia is 8.264629809290885e-8. This means something went wrong. However, I checked, again and again, to make sure the algorithms are the same, but I could not find out why the results were quite different.

Could you please give me any suggestions?

The SCE-UA code in MATLAB is written by Yarpiz, which can be found in https://github.com/smkalami/ypea110-shuffled-complex-evolution/archive/master.zip

While the code in Julia can be found in https://github.com/Undi123/SCEUA-Julia/archive/main.zip

The codes in Julia are less than 200 lines. Both scripts could run normally with just one click.

The result of SCE-UA algorithm from MATLAB is as follows
[image]

The result from Julia is as follows

[image]

The objective function is z=sum(x.^2) for both scripts, and the parameters for the algorithm were also the same. Obviously, the convergence curves are quite different. The result from Julia is not accurate enough, but I don't know why.

Now I think the problem occurs in the accuracy differences. I used the same random number sequence and run the script. After some iterations, the value Julia generated is 15 digits after the decimal point (0.4558274212090684), while the value MATLAB generated is 14 digits after the decimal point (0.455827443811707). These little differences would be accumulated and make the results quite different. It is like a chaos phenomenon, but can anybody explain this phenomenon more clearly? Because this means any heuristic algorithm implemented in MATLAB or Julia would show different performance considering accuracy and random number generator.

Comment: But the MATLAB curve has very clearly not converged at all. It's still going down... Also in general it is very unusual to start a convergence at the order of 10^1 and expect a solution at the order of 10^-60. The levels of precision at the start of your MATLAB convergence and at the end are not meaningfully comparable. The issue may be the optimization problem you are posing for the test rather than the algorithms themselves.

Comment: Hey, Collin. Yeah, the curve in MATLAB did not converge. But I set the same objective functions and same search space for MATLAB and Julia. And I expected the solution to be at similar levels of precision. But they were not. That's why I was confused. I have added this information to my question. Thanks!

Comment: I seem to remember SCE depends on random numbers generators: are you sure the generators are the same in both Matlab and Julia? And their seed? Also, 10e-60 is an unreasonable ridiculously small number: I haven’t looked at the code, but don’t the algorithms have stopping conditions?

Comment: Hey, @Infinity77, this code doesn't set stopping conditions, It merely set the max iteration number with 500 and it is not large iteration number. I think you might be right, the problem came from the random number generator. So maybe I should start another question about how to generate same random number in MATLAB and Julia.

Comment: Hey, @Infinity77, I think I knew what happened. I used the same random sequence for Julia and MATLAB. The accuracy of MATLAB is less than Julia's. With algorithm run, the value Julia generated is 15 digits after the decimal point (0.4558274212090684), while the value MATLAB generated is 14 digits after the decimal point (0.455827443811707). This makes the results of those two different. In somewhere, this little error would trigger some function and caused the error. However, I was still confused, this phenomenon is more like chaos. I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: @Infinity77, Although this problem can not be solved, I think it proved that my code is right. So I could do optimization with Julia module now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I suggest testing the algorithms on a really simple function where you know the solution *a priori*. For example, minimizing y = x^2 +1 would be a great place to start. If the Julia implementation converges to 1 while the Matlab implementation still fails to converge then you'll know where the problem is. Also, regarding random number generation, I *strongly* suggest you don't go down the rabbit hole of trying to generate the same random numbers in two different languages. It is *significantly* more difficult than you'd imagine.

Comment: @ColinTBowers, thanks for your advice. The objective function used in my cases should converge to 0. Although results for both implementations are near 0 (8e-8 for Julia and 2e-63 for MATLAB). But obviously, the result from MATLAB is more close to 0.  I just want to know why MATLAB seems to show better performance. 2e-63 is extremely small, why result of Julia can not reach that high accuracy. I generated the same random initial sequences and modified the random generator. And I found at first results were same for both scripts., but with error accumulated, results would change siginificantly.

Comment: Your metric for performance here is problematic. I would argue the Matlab algorithm is performing badly because it is not converging. However, this is most likely because of how you have specified the stopping conditions (or because of default stopping conditions). Stopping conditions are tricky when the optimal parameter solution *or* the objective function at the optimum are 0. I strongly suggest reformulating your problem so the optima is at a nice non-zero number like 1 (both the optimal parameter *and* optimal objective function value at 1 if possible).

Comment: Note also the difference between relative and absolute tolerance in stopping conditions. Honestly I've wasted weeks of my life debugging optimization algorithms and 99% of the time the issue is always in how the problem interacts with the stopping conditions.